# Error in your SQL syntax, check the manual

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the following SQL query:

```
$query="
    SELECT post_id,FIND_IN_SET(
        post_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( post_id ORDER BY meta_value * 1 DESC)
             FROM $wpdb->postmeta
             WHERE meta_key ='ma_ratings_average')
        ) AS rank
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key ='ma_ratings_average'
    AND post_id = '".$post_id."'
";
```

And since upgrading to MySQL 8, I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'rank FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key ='ma_ratings_average'

What does this mean and what's the route to resolve it?

Comment: RANK is a reserved word in MySql 8.0

Comment: @forpas So adjusting it to prefix_rank should do it?

Comment: Yes, or surround it with backticks.